# Hide sidebar and change layout Blog Page using is_page() function

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic, conditional-tags

I have two conditionals in my page.php, the first one to use col-12 or col-8 (bootstrap 4) and another to add or not the sidebar. See the code:

**col-**

```
 <?php if(!is_page(array('cart', 'checkout', 'my-account'))) : ?>

    <div class="col-md-8 blog-main">

      <?php else : ?>

    <div class="col-md-12 blog-main">

  <?php endif; ?>
```

**Sidebar**

```
  <?php if(!is_page(array('cart', 'checkout', 'my-account')) : ?>

    <div class="sidebar-module-inset">
      <?php get_sidebar(); ?>
    </div>

  <?php endif; ?>
```

Both are working, but now, I wanna hide sidebar and change the col- in my blog page and I couldn't figure out the name I use to do this.

I tryed 'blog' 'page' 'many others'.

Is anybody knows?

Tks!

Answer (score 1):

`is_page()` doesn't work for the main posts page, you need to use [`is_home()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/is_home/) to check for that condition.